# How to write if statement with own object in Java Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with if statement. I have added an external library which recognizes human gestures such as moveRight and moveLeft.

The function which returns the label looks like that:

```
private static GestureType getGestureType(float leftProb, float rightProb) {
        return (leftProb > RISE_THRESHOLD) ? GestureType.MoveLeft : GestureType.MoveRight;
    }
```

So whenever I shake my phone I will receive a Toast message  with left or write written on it.
As I have my gesture recognized I would like to make use of this.

I am trying to write a simple if statement, which later I will be able to develop but I am stuck.

[image]

What I need to do is for example after Gesture will be recognized as Right i would like to Log it,to future development

Comment: Try: gestureType == GestureType.MoveRight

Comment: GestureType is an enum, and can't be used as a boolean expression directly.

Comment: but this        if (gestureType == MotionDetector.GestureType.MoveRight){} gives me no error,so is it correct?

Comment: You could run it and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanna do:

```
if (gestureType == GestureType.MoveRight){

} else {

}
```